# Asset loading failing (Cocoa for OS X)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm very new to mac development and I have a hard time understanding how all this Cocoa stuff works.

Right now I'm working on getting still images from a video file and in order to do so, I need to load my video file (asset).

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"/Users/EVG/Desktop/myfile.mp4"];

AVURLAsset *myAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];

NSArray *keys = @[@"tracks"];

[myAsset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:keys completionHandler:^()
 {
     NSError *error = nil;
     AVKeyValueStatus tracksStatus = [myAsset statusOfValueForKey:@"tracks" error:&error];

     if ( tracksStatus == AVKeyValueStatusFailed ||
         tracksStatus == AVKeyValueStatusCancelled )
     {
         NSLog(@"Failed with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
     }
 }];
```

After this code is executed I'm getting the following message:

NSView Controller[644:4413] Failed with error: The operation could not be completed

Does anyone know how to solve this problem I'm having?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Are you sure that path is right? Usually if you're hardcoding an absolute directory, you'd want to prefix it with a slash; the vast majority of the time, I see paths like yours written as `/Users/EVG...` (with leading forward slash). That might lead to problems later, if your AVURLAsset isn't initialized properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL is wrong. First of all, absolute file paths should begin with a `/`, as in `/Users/EVG/Desktop/myfile.mp4`. However, that's not a URL. A file URL should be `file:///Users/EVG/Desktop/myfile.mp4`.

Comment: My file URL is correct, but I'm still receiving this error. Any ideas?